# Can not use colored icons for Slide Drawer

Tags: android, xml, material-design

Icons I am using here are all colored, but does not show up on the run.
I tried app:itemIconTint="@null" in xml, but no use.

```
XML CODE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
        app:itemIconTint="@null"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="@string/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_help"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

**This is another Layout file were the Slide Drawer will appear. I have deleted unnecessary code to make it simple **

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             ........../>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you using NavigationView @ Aryan ?

Comment: Yes I am using Navigation View, I am adding that XML code as well.

Comment: add this to your activity @Aryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your activity

```
navi_view.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

where navi_view is the object of your NavigationView.